For a given a non-hermitian random matrix, how large can you make its leading eigenvalue using only swaps across the diagonal?
Suppose $X$ is an $N\times N$ Ginibre random matrix. Each element of the matrix $x_{ij}$ is drawn independently from a Gaussian distribution with zero mean and variance $\mathrm{E}[x_{ij}^2]=\frac{1}{N}$.
For large $N$, it is known that the eigenvalues of $X$ are uniformly distribued in a circle in the complex plane with centre $0$ and radius $1$. In particular, the leading eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $X$ (the eigenvalue with largest real part) is $1$. This is known as the circular law.
Now define a 'swap' operation on $X$. For some indices $(i, j)$ with $i\neq j$, the 'swapped' matrix $S_{ij}(X)$ is just the matrix $X$ with the elements $x_{ij}$ and $x_{ji}$ swapped round. For example, if $N=3$ we could have
\begin{align}
X &= \left(\begin{matrix}x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\ x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}\end{matrix}\right),\\
%
S_{12}(X) &= \left(\begin{matrix}x_{11} & x_{21} & x_{13} \\ x_{12} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\ x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}\end{matrix}\right).
\end{align}
I'm interested in the following question: Given a realisation of $X$, how much larger can the leading eigenvalue $X$ be made using only the swap operation? And, conversely, how much smaller can we make it? The swap operation can be used an arbitrary number of times and on any elements.
I have done some simple numerical experimentation using a hill-climbing algorithm on $200\times 200$ matrices and it seems like the answer is that you can increase the largest eigenvalue by around 40% and decrease it by around 10% (very roughly). The algorithm randomly swaps some elements of $X$ and computes the leading eigenvalue, if the leading eigenvlaue is larger than the matrix without swaps, then this matrix is fed back into the algorithm. I ran 2000 iterations of this process.
Result of numerical expriments. The original matrix has $\lambda_1=0.92$, when trying to maximise $\lambda_1$ using swaps we have $\lambda_1=1.31$, when minimising we have $\lambda_1=0.85$
I have also tried some analytics. If we call $E_{ij}$ the $N\times N$ matrix with a one at position $(i, j)$ and zeros everywhere else, then we have
\begin{align}
     S_{ij}(X) = X + (x_{ji}-x_{ij})(E_{ij} - E_{ji}).
\end{align}
If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $S_{ij}(X)$, but not of $X$, then we can write
\begin{align}
     \det\left[\lambda I - S_{ij}(X)\right] = 0 \leftrightarrow \det\left[I - G(\lambda)(x_{ji}-x_{ij})(E_{ij} - E_{ji})\right]=0,
\end{align}
where $I$ is the $N\times N$ identity matrix and $G(\lambda) = (\lambda I - X)^{-1}$ is the resolvent matrix of $X$.
To make further progress, I have used three properties of the resolvent matrix $G$. The first is that, when $N$ is large, the off diagonal elements of $G$ are sub-leading compared to the diagonal elements. The second is that, outside of the eigenvalue spectrum of $X$, the trace of the resolvent matrix is $\mathrm{Tr}~ G(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$. The third, which I am less sure of, is that the variance of the diagonal elements of $G$ is also sub-leading for large $N$. The upshot of these properties (the third of which may or may not be valid) is that the resolvent matrix can be written as $G(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.
If these properties of the resolvent are true, then we can deduce the following
\begin{align}
     \det\left[I - G(\lambda)(x_{ji}-x_{ij})(E_{ij} - E_{ji})\right] = 1 + \frac{1}{\lambda^2}(x_{ji}-x_{ij})^2 = 0.
\end{align}
However, the solutions to this equation have real part equal to zero, and therefore they cannot explain the numerical evidence: that swaps can increase and decrease the leading eigenvalue by a significant margin. A similar formula holds if we consider multiple swaps, in particular, I think we run into the same problem.
I think that my error is one of two places, and both are due to my assumptions about the structure of the resolvent matrix of large Ginibre random matrices. Perhaps the sub-leading off diagonal terms in $G(\lambda)$ cannot be neglected? Or maybe it isn't valid to simply set $G(\lambda)$ equal to a constant times the identity matrix? Or perhaps there is a simpler approach? Any help, analytical or numerical, would be appreciated.
